# Threaded C programs in minGW

Tags: c, mingw

I am creating a program that intercepts all packets when a **certain** link is down. I would need to implement the sniffer and the link-checker as threads. But minGW does not have pthreads.

How do you implement threads in minGW?

**Edit:answer**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/sync.aspx

Vivek Goel led me to this (_beginthread). Both examples compile on Code::blocks/minGW!

Comment: Windows doesn't have pthreads. You need Win32 threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 
WIN 32 Threads API see 
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Use_the_thread_library
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684254(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

MinGW doesn't provide a full POSIX model. If you want threads in the standard package, you'll have to use the Windows variety.

It states on the MinGW [main page](http://www.mingw.org/):

> MinGW compilers provide access to the functionality of the Microsoft C runtime and some language-specific runtimes. MinGW, being Minimalist, **does not, and never will, attempt to provide a POSIX runtime environment for POSIX application deployment on MS-Windows.** If you want POSIX application deployment on this platform, please consider Cygwin instead.

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) *does* have pthreads support because it provides the Cygwin DLL, an emulation layer, whereas MinGW is more gcc for use with the Windows way of doing things.

Alternatively, if Cygwin isn't an option, you can look into [Pthreads/Win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/announcement.html) which claims to work with MinGW.

Comment: Wikipedia provides a link for a x64 patch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads#Pthreads-w32:_Open_Source_POSIX_Threads_for_Win32

Answer (score 3):

With MinGW you have some options.
My recomendations:

1. Use native Windows API to make your threads.
2. Use a good library to manage that. I usually use a C++ framework called JUCE to have a
   better life.

Using Windows API you could try something like this:

```
/*
 *  main.c
 *
 *  Created on: 18/10/2011
 *  Author: Cesar Carlos Ortiz Pantoja.
 */

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int exitCondition;

struct threadParams{
    int param1;
    int param2;
};

static DWORD WINAPI myFirstThread(void* threadParams)
{
    struct threadParams* params = (struct threadParams*)threadParams;

    while(exitCondition){
        printf("My Thread! Param1:%d, Param2:%d\n", params->param1, params->param2);
        fflush(stdout);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    DWORD threadDescriptor;
    struct threadParams params1 = {1, 2};
    exitCondition = 1;

    CreateThread(
        NULL,                   /* default security attributes.   */
        0,                      /* use default stack size.        */
        myFirstThread,          /* thread function name.          */
        (void*)&params1,        /* argument to thread function.   */
        0,                      /* use default creation flags.    */
        &threadDescriptor);     /* returns the thread identifier. */

    while(1){
        printf("Main Program!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Regards

Comment: You shouldn't be calling CreateThread.  You should be using _beginthread and _beginthreadex instead, otherwise you're going to have problems!

Comment: We should be listening to Brett here.  Some people don't know how to read.  http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Use_the_thread_library